# Как проверить, являются ли имена столбцов индексом?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, index

Подскажите способ проверки index для наименования колонок. Соответсвенно, нужно проверить, является ли он `RangeIndex` или же наименования колонок получили корректные названия.

Пример `df`:

```
           0     1         2           3       4
0 2021-04-25  None       int          6785    2271
1 2021-04-25  None       int          6796     1
```

или `df` может быть сформирован с наименованием колок:

```
       date     Ab       dir           cd     count
0 2021-04-25  None       int          6785    2271
1 2021-04-25  None       int          6796     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну прямо так и проверяйте:

```
if isinstance(df.columns, (pd.Int64Index, pd.RangeIndex)):
    ...
```

Comment: Только `df.columns` судя по вопросу всё-таки )  Прикольно, я уже через `all` ответ писал, но так лучше конечно

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо! посыпаю голову пеплом)